# How to find the next SQL Server Replication Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I am debugging my database and I am finding that the replication is failing on a delete statement.

I look at the source and destination tables and they are the same.  So someone deleted a row from the source and then put it back in.  (The delete fails because of a FK reference to some manual data that I don't want to cascade delete.)

Is there a way to find out the PK of the row it is trying to delete?

(All Replication monitor will tell me is the name of the FK that is causing the delete statement to fail.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.  I'll tell you the easy one (because I'm lazy).  Put a trace on your subscriber for non-successful stored procedure executions.  You should get a hit for one called something like sp_MSdel_table (where table is the name of your table).  The argument(s) to that procedure will be the primary key of the record that it's trying to delete.

Easy way number two is to modify the sproc identified in the previous method not to be angry at a missing row (after all, it's just going to delete it so the fact that's it's now missing isn't *that* big a deal).  You might have other non-convergence issues, but at least you can get your commands flowing again. (EDIT: Just noticed the reason for your issue.  I'd advise not having FK constraints at the subscriber since any referential integrity should be taken care of at the publisher.  I'll make your replication faster when SQL doesn't have to check that each time it does an applicable insert, update, or delete).

Hard way number one involves looking at the error in replication monitor an noting that there's a transaction id and sequence number specified.  You then use a sproc in the distribution database to get the text of the command being executed.

Hard way number two involved diffing the tables either with tablediff.exe, something like RedGate's SQLCompare, or a roll-your-own join over linked servers to show the difference.  Keep this in your back pocket just in case one of the other one-row-at-a-time methods mentioned above doesn't do it for you.  My threshold for such things is about three.  YMMV.